# How to normalize text with regex?

Tags: python, regex, text-normalization

How to normilize text with regex with some if statements?

If we have string like this
`One T933 two, three35.4. four 9,3 8.5 five M2x13 M4.3x2.1`

And I want to normilize like this
`one t 933 two three 35.4 four 9,3 8.5 five m2x13 m4.3x2.1`

1. Remove all dots and commas.
2. Split number and string if not starts with letter 'M' `T933` --> `T 933`
3. All lowercase
4. Do not split if there is dot or comma between numbers `35.4` --> `35.4` or `9,3` --> `9.3` if there is comma between, then replace to dot

What I am able to do is this

```
def process(str, **kwargs):
    str = str.replace(',', '.')
    str = re.split(r'(-?\d*\.?\d+)', str)
    str = ' '.join(str)
    str.lower()
    return str
```

but there is no if condition when numbers starts with letter 'M' and their also is splitted.
And in some reason after string process i get some unnecessary spaces.

Is there some ideas how to do that with regex? Or with help methods like replace, lower, join and so on?

Comment: Does `re.sub(r'[.,](?!(?<=\d.)\d)', '', re.sub(r'(?<=[^\W\d_])(?<![MmXx])(?=\d)', ' ', text)).lower()` work as expected?

Comment: looks good, but if there is something like this `aa88aa` what I need is `aa 88 aa`, but there  this command just split first numbers and letters. What i need to modify to split all nubers and letters in one substring(word)  `aa99bb88cc77` --> `aa 99 bb 88 cc 77`

Comment: So, `re.sub(r'[.,](?!(?<=\d.)\d)', '', re.sub(r'(?<=[^\W\d_])(?<![MmXx])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[^\W\d_])', ' ', text)).lower()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest a solution like

```py
re.sub(r'[.,](?!(?<=\d.)\d)', '', re.sub(r'(?<=[^\W\d_])(?<![MmXx])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[^\W\d_])', ' ', text)).lower()
```

The outer `re.sub` is meant to remove dots or commas when not between digits:

- `[.,]` - a comma or dot
- `(?!(?<=\d.)\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the right, that is immediately preceded with a digit + any one char

The inner `re.sub` replaces with a space the following pattern:

- `(?<=[^\W\d_])(?<![MmXx])(?=\d)` - a location between a letter (`[^\W\d_]` matches any letter) and a digit (see `(?=\d)`), where the letter is not `M` or `X` (case insensitive, `[MmXx]` can be written as `(?i:[mx])`)
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\d)(?=[^\W\d_])` - a location between a digit and a letter.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/uY9IOs):

```py
import re
text = 'One T933 two, three35.4. four 9,3 8.5 five M2x13 M4.3x2.1 aa88aa'
print( re.sub(r'[.,](?!(?<=\d.)\d)', '', re.sub(r'(?<=[^\W\d_])(?<![MmXx])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[^\W\d_])', ' ', text)).lower() )
```

Output:

```
one t 933 two three 35.4 four 9,3 8.5 five m2 x13 m4.3 x2.1 aa 88 aa
```